# Python: Converting Datetime into an integer

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have an excel file with two columns, one is written as 'YYYY/MM/DD' and the other is written as 'HH:MM:SS'. I then combined the two columns to create a 'datetime' column that returns
'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS' in a string format.

```
df['datetime'] = df['YYYY/MM/DD'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['HH:MM:SS'].astype(str) 
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

Now I want to convert datetime to an integer but am having no luck. This is what I have tried to do:

```
df['wtime'] = int(float(df['datetime']))
```

I just want an integer value returned so I can eventually get the start and end time of the data set.

Comment: "*so I can eventually get the start and end time of the data set*" - why would you need an integer for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to convert your df['datetime'] you can do

`df['newCol'] = df['datetime'].apply(lambda x: int(x.timestamp()))`

this will create a column newCol containing the Unix timestamp as an integer

Answer (score 0):

you can use this or another.

```
import datetime
current_date = datetime.datetime.now()
print("String Format of Current Date and Time:", current_date)
# String Format of Current Date and Time: 2022-11-16 13:19:43.211656
```

or

```
curr_date_str = str(current_date)
curr_date_strip = curr_date_str.split('.')[0]
curr_date_strip = curr_date_strip.replace(':', '')
curr_date_strip = curr_date_strip.replace('-', '')
curr_date_strip = curr_date_strip.replace(' ', '')
print("Stripped Format of Current Date and Time:", int(curr_date_strip))
# Stripped Format of Current Date and Time: 20221112200439
```